# How to resolve app processDebugResources error?

Tags: java, android, xml, debugging, build

When I apply changes ..I get a debug error of resources not found ..though there's absolutely nothing wrong with the resource format moreover there are no errors in the xml files(the drawables are present)..so what could be causing this problem?

ERROR MESSAGE :

> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:processDebugResources
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_market.xml","position":{"startLine":76}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_market.xml:77: AAPT: error: resource drawable/search (aka elevation.mi:drawable/search) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_new_profile.xml","position":{"startLine":43}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_new_profile.xml:44: AAPT: error: resource drawable/verified (aka elevation.mi:drawable/verified) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_new_profile.xml","position":{"startLine":350}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_new_profile.xml:351: AAPT: error: resource drawable/rectangle_11 (aka elevation.mi:drawable/rectangle_11) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_notifications.xml","position":{"startLine":36}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_notifications.xml:37: AAPT: error: resource drawable/red_circle (aka elevation.mi:drawable/red_circle) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_profile.xml","position":{"startLine":390}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_profile.xml:391: AAPT: error: resource drawable/rectangle_11 (aka elevation.mi:drawable/rectangle_11) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_selection_reset_password.xml","position":{"startLine":81}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_selection_reset_password.xml:82: AAPT: error: resource drawable/phone (aka elevation.mi:drawable/phone) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_selection_reset_password.xml","position":{"startLine":129}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_selection_reset_password.xml:130: AAPT: error: resource drawable/via_email (aka elevation.mi:drawable/via_email) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_test_player.xml","position":{"startLine":135}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_test_player.xml:136: AAPT: error: resource drawable/nopath___copy__24_ (aka elevation.mi:drawable/nopath___copy__24_) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_test_player.xml","position":{"startLine":226}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_test_player.xml:227: AAPT: error: resource drawable/nopath___copy__9_ (aka elevation.mi:drawable/nopath___copy__9_) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_test_player.xml","position":{"startLine":287}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_test_player.xml:288: AAPT: error: resource drawable/repeatoff (aka elevation.mi:drawable/repeatoff) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\album_options.xml","position":{"startLine":37}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\album_options.xml:38: AAPT: error: resource drawable/rectangle_outline (aka elevation.mi:drawable/rectangle_outline) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\album_options.xml","position":{"startLine":52}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\album_options.xml:53: AAPT: error: resource drawable/rectangle_outline (aka elevation.mi:drawable/rectangle_outline) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\comments_view.xml","position":{"startLine":46}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\comments_view.xml:47: AAPT: error: resource drawable/play_black (aka elevation.mi:drawable/play_black) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\custom_pd.xml","position":{"startLine":15}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\custom_pd.xml:16: AAPT: error: resource drawable/pd (aka elevation.mi:drawable/pd) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\details_item.xml","position":{"startLine":58}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\details_item.xml:59: AAPT: error: resource drawable/rectangle_19 (aka elevation.mi:drawable/rectangle_19) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\edit_album.xml","position":{"startLine":40}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\edit_album.xml:41: AAPT: error: resource drawable/rectangle_outline (aka elevation.mi:drawable/rectangle_outline) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\edit_album.xml","position":{"startLine":54}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\edit_album.xml:55: AAPT: error: resource drawable/rectangle_outline (aka elevation.mi:drawable/rectangle_outline) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\expanded_cover_photo.xml","position":{"startLine":58}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\expanded_cover_photo.xml:59: AAPT: error: resource drawable/rectangle_11 (aka elevation.mi:drawable/rectangle_11) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_genre.xml","position":{"startLine":34}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_genre.xml:35: AAPT: error: resource drawable/search (aka elevation.mi:drawable/search) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_market.xml","position":{"startLine":34}}],"original":"ERROR:C:\Users\sharon\AndroidStudioProjects\Elevation2\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_market.xml:35: AAPT: error: resource drawable/search (aka elevation.mi:drawable/search) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out an error in a single xml file can cause multiple erros ?? Well that's something I've just discovered..but instead of getting an error message for that specific xml layout I got tons of errors from all my layouts which created a massive confusion because usually you'd get an error message from where the error has been performed.

This is how I was able to fix it :

1. Copied the drawable file in res/
2. Pasted the file In a different folder..outside the project
3. Permanently deleted the drawable file (in the project NB :..not the one I copied )
4. Restarted android studio
5. Imported the copied drawable file in resource manager ( this created a new indexing)
6. clicked "apply changes "
   7 then boom! The actual error appears .this time It was not all the xml files
   8 . Fixed the error ( color name)
7. Applied changes and everything went well